# Categorical semantics of W-types

Tags: ct.category-theory, type-theory

Jacob's book titled "Categorical Logic and Type Theory" gives a nice description of Π and Σ types as adjunctions to substitution functors induced by display maps.  Is there a similar categorical description of W-types (and maybe M-types while we are at it)?

Comment: The title of the question has a typo which should be fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The categorical semantics of W-types, as initial algebras, have been studied in the following paper of Moerdijk and Palmgren: "Wellfounded trees in categories", Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 104(2000), 189 - 218.

Comment: And for M-types (as terminal coalgebras) there is the dual paper "Non-well-founded trees in categories" by van den Berg and de Marchi, APAL 146 (2007) 40–59.

Answer (score 3):

Also, this may be helpfull —
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polynomial+functor
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/W-type